# Get password for node-cli and pass it on to next command in nodejs

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

Im trying to build a command line interface using nodejs. I have used enquirer package to prompt users for questions. I have a scenario where i need to write to /etc/hosts file. I tried running the following command using execa package

```js
const {stdout} = await execa.command('echo "192.241.xx.xx  venus.example.com venus" >> /etc/hosts', { cwd: '/etc/'})
```

But it does not seems to work and tried with sudo command as well

```js
const {stdout} = await execa.command("sudo vim hosts", { cwd: '/etc/'});
```

How to execute it in nodejs. Basically i wanted to prompt the user for password and then need to write it to /etc/hosts file.

FYKI: im using execa for executing shell commands.
Tried the [hostile.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hostile) and it didn't work either.

Here is the full code

```js
async function executeCommand() {
  try {
    const {stdout} = await execa.command("echo '192.34.0.03 subdomain.domain.com' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts", { cwd: '/etc/'});
    console.log(stdout);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Node package for this purpose, called [password-prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/password-prompt):

```
let prompt = require('password-prompt');
let password = prompt('password: ');
```

And now that you have the password, you can run something like this:

```
let command = `echo "${password}" | sudo -S -k vim /etc/hosts`;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```js
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec)
const nameOutput = await exec("echo '127.0.0.1 test.com' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts")
```

This would prompt password to enter.